# Can you deploy a express server on netlify and a react project on netlify and connect the two?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express, netlify

My React project is online but is not fully functioning because it cannot access my express server or psql database. Is there a way to deploy my restful api & express server on netlify? If not, where should I deploy?

Comment: Yes you can avail netlify-functions:https://www.netlify.com/blog/2018/09/13/how-to-run-express.js-apps-with-netlify-functions/

Comment: @a2441918 Thank you very much! Is this the easiest way to do this if I want the project to be free?

Comment: Yes, its simple to use Heroku as well. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can with netlify functions, but I would recommend Heroku

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you know or want to learn about serverless architecture. Netlify offers FaunaDB and serverless functions for your API. They offer a free plan and you'd have to evaluate whether it fits your needs.

If you intend on working with Postgres, you will have to host the database yourself or get a managed one from, for example, AWS or Digital Ocean. Check out Heroku as well. They have free tiers as well and [they offer Postgres as their database](https://www.heroku.com/pricing#data-services).

Comment: Thank you, is it difficult to host a db on your own if you are only getting about 100 req a day?

Comment: This is a weird question to answer. Is it hard to run a web server? Yes and no. It's very easy when you don't do anything crazy and don't overload it. Same goes to databases, but there will be different problems to solve - backups, query optimization.

With 100 requests per day, I'd use SQLite. It's a single file but the performance is crazy, if you're okay with its limitations.

Comment: Thank you I will give SQLite try!